# is there a way to get cousin element class wihout jquery?

Tags: javascript

i want to get the class track-songs in cousin element of 'p' to get the value of 'i Love', my starting element is when i clicked show lyrics (show using arrow) that is i started using 'a', there are example in jquery but i need to do this using javascript for my homework.

**Image**

[image]

just how can i do that wihtout jquery??

Comment: @Pete "without jQuery" ...

Comment: Haha long day! Thought it said with, probably because OP can't spell without ;p

Comment: Try: `anchor.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".track-songs")`

Comment: @Titus anchor means is an a?

Comment: Yes, the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `this` here refers to the clicked show lyrics link `<a>` element, then you can use the js [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method inside `addEventListener()` like:

```
const text = this.closest('popular-item.column').querySelector('.track-songs').textContent;
```

**Demo:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("click", function(){
    const text = this.closest('popular-item.column').querySelector('.track-songs').textContent;
    console.clear()
    console.log( text )
  });
});
```

```html
<popular-item class="column">
  <div class="card-content">
    <p class="track-songs">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <a href="#">Show Lyrics</a>
  </div>
</popular-item>
<popular-item class="column">
  <div class="card-content">
    <p class="track-songs">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <a href="#">Show Lyrics</a>
  </div>
</popular-item>
```

Comment: waw, you are a god, how did you know that i use an addeventlistener, and the exact answer precisely??,

Comment: It all comes with experience and daily coding :)

Comment: I’ve been trying to find a good way to access a cousin element. Is this the best way when you can’t latch on to a specific class? Go to closest grandfather then query select down to the element?